# Website displays correctly in chrome and FF but not IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Can anyone tell me some of the main things to look for when your website displays correctly in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE. It seems my CSS styling isn't getting applied.

Please look at my site below (ignore the design):

http://acews.x10.mx/index.php

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some screen shots of what's not rendering properly along with the versions of IE that are problematic.

Answer (score 3):

You've declared no `DOCTYPE`.  IE hates that.

[http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://acews.x10.mx/index.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Your best bet would be to correct each error on the validator page and try it again.

Comment: I had a stupid issue with INCLUDED PHP files at the very top, so it wasn't working ... then I put <!doctype html> at the very top and lowered the included files and it worked perfectly. | Thank you Sparky